# $\mathbb{E}[X^+]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^-]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering what is the relationship between $\mathbb{E}[X^+]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^-]$, when $\mathbb{E}$ is a sublineair expectation and $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[-X] = 0, \mathbb{E}[X^2] > - \mathbb{E}[-X^2]$.

Comment: You might want to recall (even briefly) what a **sublinear** expectation is, if only to avoid that people answer your question in the context of usual expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating the equation $X = X^+ - X^-$ we get $E[X^+]=E[X^-]$.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get a different answer when you use:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}[X^-] & = & \mathbb{E}[\max(-x,0)] \\
 & = & \int^{\infty}_{0} (-x) f(x) dx \\
 & = & - \mathbb{E}[X^+]
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: First of all, you must notice that your result has to be wrong, because both $X^-$ and $X^+$ are non-negative. The mistake is that your second equality should write $\displaystyle E[\max\{-x,0\}] = \int_{-\infty}^0(-x)f(x)\,dx$